# Kendo ui autocomplete cascading

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, html-select, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm in front of a strange problem with 2 kendo cascading dropdownlist :

- First dropdown : it's a list of countries, user can write and can be helped with autocomplete (Filter(FilterType.StartsWith) and IgnoreCase(true))
  It works perfectly
- Second dropdown : it's a list of all the cities of the selected country (from the first dropdownlist). Same configuration as the first: (Filter(FilterType.StartsWith) and IgnoreCase(true))
  The filter and ignorecase doesn't works, when I wrote in the dropdown I have a "Contains" filter and case sensitive, the default values...

Here is my code :

```
        <span>Country:</span>
    @(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
              .Name("countries")
              .DataTextField("CountryName")
              .DataValueField("CountryId")
              .Filter(FilterType.StartsWith)
              .IgnoreCase(true)
              .Placeholder("Select a country...")
              .DataSource(source =>
              {
                  source.Read(read =>
                  {
                      read.Action("GetCascadeCountries", "Home");
                  });
              })
            )

    <span>City:</span>
    @(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
              .Name("cities")
              .DataTextField("CityName")
              .DataValueField("CityId")
              .Filter(FilterType.StartsWith)
              .IgnoreCase(true)
              .Placeholder("Select a city...")
              .DataSource(source =>
              {
                  source.Read(read =>
                  {
                      read.Action("GetCascadeCities", "Home")
                          .Data("filterCities");
                  })
                  .ServerFiltering(true);
              })
              .Enable(false)
              .AutoBind(false)
              .CascadeFrom("countries")
            )
    <script>
        function filterCities() {
            return {
                brands: $('#countries').val(),
                cityFilter: $('#cities').data('kendoComboBox').input.val()
            };
        }
    </script>
```

Anyone can help me ? Maybe I forgot something...

Comment: No one can help me on this ? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the solution, it was in my "GetCascadeCities" controller methods.